# Backspace to go one level up

Tags: autohotkey

This is my slightly modified version of [kidmar's script from AHK forums](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/22194-vista-explorer-backspace-for-parent-folder-as-in-xp/).

The script should change `Backspace` key behaviour, i.e. when we press `Backspace` in Windows Explorer, it works like `Alt-Up` (we go up one level in files hierarchy).

For some reason it doesn't work. How it should be fixed?

```
FunBackspaceExplorer()
{
    IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
    {
        ControlGetFocus, focused, A
        IfNotInString, focused, "Edit" ; Return true only if current control isn't an edit control
            return 1
    }

    return 0
}

#If, FunBackspaceExplorer() ; Backspace hotkey exists only if all conditions are met
Backspace:: SendInput, !{Up}
#If
```

(There are another working solutions for this task, but I'm interseted in this one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version works on my system, if I use:

```
#If, FunBackspaceExplorer() ; Backspace hotkey exists only if all conditions are met

    Backspace:: 
    SetKeyDelay 10,1000
    SendEvent {Alt down}{Up down}{Alt Up}{Up Up}
    return

#If
```

**[SetKeyDelay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm)** inserts a delay between a down event and up event for a send, or a delay after sending keys.
It does not work with SendInput.

Comment: on my system it doesnt notice the rename in progress situation correctly